# WPF MVVM changing viewmodel calls dependency property on old viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a TabViewModel wich contains a dependency property CurrentViewModel. The CurrentViewModel property is bound to a ContentControl in the view TabView.xaml. The TabViewModel also contains a command to change the CurrentViewModel to a ProductViewModel:

```
 public class TabViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    public string TabName { get; set; }
    //public List<BaseViewModel> ViewModels { get; set; }

    private PageViewModel _currentViewModel;
    public PageViewModel CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return _currentViewModel; }
        set
        {
            _currentViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }

    public TabViewModel(string tabName, PageViewModel currentViewModel)
    {
        TabName = tabName;
        CurrentViewModel = currentViewModel;
    }

    private ICommand _navigateToProductViewModelCommand;
    public ICommand NavigateToProductViewModelCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_navigateToProductViewModelCommand == null)
            {
                _navigateToProductViewModelCommand = new DelegateCommand<Product>(
                      (p) =>
                      {
                          CurrentViewModel = new ProductViewModel();
                      });
            }

            return _navigateToProductViewModelCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

TabView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Monitoring_Tool.Views.TabView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel.PageProgress}" Height="5" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,10">

        <ProgressBar.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                            <Border  BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Background="LightGray" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0">
                                <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#00B6FA" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ProgressBar.Style>

    </ProgressBar>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel}" Grid.Row="1" />

</Grid>
```

I instantiate the TabViewModel like this:

```
new TabViewModel("Producten", new ProductsViewModel())
```

The ProductsView.xaml is shown like it should be. In the ProductsView.xaml I call the command from the TabViewModel like this:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding
            MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateToProductViewModelCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:TabView}}}"/>
        </DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

When the datagrid is empty, the command is executed and ProductView.xaml appears like it should be. But when the datagrid is not empty somthing strange happens:

the command is executed, and when I debug I can see that the currentViewModel is changed to ProductViewModel. Then when OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel") is called. There is a set call (value = null) to a depedency property (SelectedAssetCategory) on the ProductsViewModel, wich was replaced and doesn't exits anymore?!

When I put CurrentViewModel = null the same thing happens, I can only do CurrentViewModel = new ProductsViewModel. So I guess it's somthing with updating the UI?

In the App.xaml I defined the following recources:

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:TabViewModel}">
        <views:TabView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ProductsViewModel}">
        <views:ProductsView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ProductViewModel}">
        <views:ProductView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

The ProductsViewModel looks like this:

```
    class ProductsViewModel: PageViewModel
{
    private readonly MonitotingToolEntities _databaseEntities;

    public ProductsViewModel()
    {
          _databaseEntities = new MonitotingToolEntities();

        AssetCategories = new ObservableCollection<AssetCategory>(_databaseEntities.AssetCategory.ToList())
        {
            new AssetCategory() {AssetCategoryID = 0, AssetCategoryName = "Alles"}
        };

        Results = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AssetCategory> AssetCategories { get; set; }

    private AssetCategory _selectedAssetCategory;
    public AssetCategory SelectedAssetCategory
    {
        get { return _selectedAssetCategory; }
        set
        {
            _selectedAssetCategory = value; //this one is called with value = null
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAssetCategory");
            Filter();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Results { get; set; }

    public void Filter()
    {
        Results.Clear();

        List<Product> products =
            SelectedAssetCategory.AssetCategoryID == 0
                ? _databaseEntities.Product.ToList()
                : SelectedAssetCategory.Product.ToList();

        foreach (Product product in products)
        {
            Results.Add(product);
        }
    }
}
```

ProductsView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Monitoring_Tool.Views.ProductsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Monitoring_Tool.Views"
         xmlns:componentModel="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Monitoring_Tool.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.Resources>


    <CollectionViewSource  x:Key="CvsAssetCategories" Source="{Binding Path= AssetCategories}" >
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="AssetCategoryID"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CvsResults" Source="{Binding Path= Results}" >
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="AssetCategory.AssetCategoryName" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="ImageDisabledStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Margin="0, 0, 0, 10" Grid.Row="0">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Asset Categorie:" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>

        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CvsAssetCategories}}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="AssetCategoryName"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAssetCategory}"
                  Margin="0,0,10,0"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Zoeken:" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>

        <ComboBox Grid.Column="4" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSearchField}"
                  Margin="0,0,10,0"/>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SearchQuery, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 Grid.Column="5" Margin="0,0,10,0">
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=SearchCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SearchQuery}" Key="Enter" />
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
        </TextBox>

        <Button Grid.Column="6"
                Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding SearchQuery}"
                Padding="5,0,5,0" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
            <Button.Content>
                <Image Source="/Recourses/SearchIcon.png"
                    Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ImageDisabledStyle}}"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>

        <Button Grid.Column="7"
                Command="{Binding CancelSearchCommand}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding CancelSearchEnabled}"
                Padding="5,0,5,0">
            <Button.Content>
                <Image Source="/Recourses/CancelSearchIcon.png" 
                    Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ImageDisabledStyle}}"/>
            </Button.Content>

        </Button>
    </Grid>


    <DataGrid Name="DgProducts" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              RowHeaderWidth="0" Margin="0,0,0,10" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True"
              SelectionMode="Single" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              EnableRowVirtualization="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CvsResults}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}">

        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>

        <DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding
            MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateToProductViewModelCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:TabView}}}"
                />
        </DataGrid.InputBindings>

        <DataGrid.Resources>

            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" x:Key="DgVerticalColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
               Color="LightGray"/>

            <SolidColorBrush  x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey }" 
               Color="Black"/>

        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Background="DarkGray" Padding="2,0,0,0"/>
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Manager.ManagerName}" Header="Manager" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ProductName}" Header="Product" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=MonitoringBy}" Header="Monitoring door" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=AumProduct}" Header="AUM Product (mln)"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=AumProductDate, StringFormat='{}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}'}" Header="Datum AUM Product" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=AumStrategy}" Header="AUM Strategie (mln)" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=AumStrategyDate, StringFormat='{}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}'}" Header="Datum AUM Strategie" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Aum}" Header="AUM (mln)" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TotalExpenseRatio}" Header="TER (bp)" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Fee}" Header="Total Fee" />

    </DataGrid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Results.Count, StringFormat='{}{0} Producten'}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>

        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                Content="Toevoegen"
                Padding="5,0,5,0" Margin="0,0,10,0"
                Command="{Binding AddProductCommand}" />

        <Button Grid.Column="3"
                Content="Verwijderen" 
                Padding="5,0,5,0"
                Command="{Binding Path=RemoveProductCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedProduct}"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

PageViewModel is an abstract class:

```
 public abstract class PageViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    private int _pageProgress;
    public int PageProgress
    {
        get { return _pageProgress; }
        set
        {
            _pageProgress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PageProgress");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be easier to diagnose if we could see the XAML that binds the 'TabViewModel' and the related 'SelectedAssetCategory' property, preferably the XAML for the entire 'DataGrid'. The relationship between the 'TabViewModel', 'PageViewModel' and the structure of the UI is not clear.

Comment: @karmasponge I added the the xaml files. The TabView is the root view,wich contains the view from CurrentViewModel. CurrentViewModel must be inhert from PageViewModel

Comment: I believe the issue is related to the way the default WPF 'ComboBox.SelectedItem' dependancy property works but I'll have to confirm. I cannot see anything obviously wrong with the code (though it may be worth creating a stripped down version to isolate it).

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of weird but it has something to do with the collectionviewsource (CvsAssetCategories) bound to the combobox. If I bind directly to the combobox without using the collectionviewsource the dependency property is not called. However, I like to use the collectionviewsource for the sortdescriptor. My solution now is a not null check on the setter from the dependency property, but I think its nasty way to go.